# Dynamically added column to sql results

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

I'd like to have sql results containing dynamically added fields. The picture I attached explains what I aim at.

As far I've made up something like below, yet it doesn't work.

```
SELECT s.num, s.name ( SELECT g.grade AS g.subject FROM grades g WHERE g.student = s.id ) FROM students s;
```

Note that I want to have column name corresponding to value of column `subject`.
I have no idea how to get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to construct Dynamic Sql with prepared statements.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/06/20/mysql-dynamic-sql-with-execute-and-prepare-statements/

The columns would come back like "as history" ... "as math"

As far as the nulls that is just common outer join action

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be only nice way having not gotten out of pure SQL.